# What values from these colums (jos_content) means?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I would like to be sure about meaning values from columns in jos_content table:

- modified
- published
- publish_up
- publish_down

Could someone give me any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modified : date time when the article was last modified

published : i couldn't see any field named published in that table

publish_up : date-time when you want that article to be published

publish_down : date time when you want that article to be unpublished

Comment: published is next to published_by.